# How do I capitalise the abbreviated cross-reference prefix with cleverref?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

The command `\cref{eq: eq-3}` produces `eq. (3)`, but instead, I want `Eq. (3)`, on the other hand `\Cref{eq: eq-3}` produces `Equation (3)` which is also not what I want.

Thus how do I achieve capitalisation of abbreviated prefixes not only for equations but all of the cross-references?

Comment: Have you tried passing `capitalise` to the package options?

Comment: @Troy yes it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\Cref` is not supposed to be viewed as the capitalized version of `\cref`, as it is used in the context of the start of a sentence, and is thus non-abbreviated (e.g. `\Cref{<lbl>} shows...` gives `Equation 3 shows...`).
Whereas `\cref` is the abbreviated form, which will give `eq. 3` and should only be used in the middle of a sentence.

To change all of the abbreviated forms (i.e. obtained with `\cref`) to capitalized form, `cleveref` package offers the `capitalise` option.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{test}
    a+b
\end{equation}
\Cref{test} should be used at the start of the sentence, whereas \cref{test} now shows capitalized abbreviations.
\end{document}
```

[image: cleveref capitalization]